# How to make one class template method's instantiation to be equal to other in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

Let's say, there is the following class template:

```
template<char type>
class A
{
public:
  // ...
  void worker_method();
};

// Instantiation for the 'c'-type.
template<>
void A<'c'>::worker_method()
{
  // Do something specific for the 'c'-type.
}
```

It's pretty simple, but, let's say, I'd like to have the `worker_method`'s instantiation for the `A<'C'>` to be equal to the `A<'c'>`.

**EDIT:**

I need the same `worker_method`'s instantiation independently from the `type`'s case. For example, for 'c' and 'C' -- theirs own, for 'f' and 'F' -- theirs own, but, let's say, for the 'e' and 'E' -- different ones.

Comment: Common helper function, `if constexpr` in the primary template, ...?

Comment: Are there other methods? Do they need to be the same as well? Some of them?

Comment: Work around: have a delegation template that calls the other one with a tolower.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, there are other methods, but the `worker_method`'s instantiation should be the same for particular types sets (for example, for 'c' and 'C' -- theirs own, for 'f' and 'F' -- theirs own, but, let's say, for the 'e' and 'E' -- different ones).

Comment: @SergeRoussak: That "delegation template" can be specialized such that `worker_method_impl<'C'>`  simply calls `worker_method_impl<'c'>`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a compiler that supports concepts/requires?

Then your solution could look like this [see working code on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEIJLSAA6oCoRODB7evnrJqY4CIWGRLDFxXLaY9vkMQgRMxASZPn4BdpgO6bX1BIUR0bHx0gp1DU3Z5cPdvcWlEgCUtqhexMjsHOYAzKHI3lgA1CYbbk7DxJish9gmGgCC1zcEmCyJBo%2BHbsgI9XsEAJ6JmEu9x2TAUCj2d1uJgA7FZbokvFFaHhkCB7ns9gB6TF7AB0%2BPRewAbqg8Og9gB3EgAa1iAH02AQEBgIHNDnC7tCACLs%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%2BTEJWZSUKY11GYc1T7tVyr7xR%2B5lsr1F4Yv1hWtc%2BI2deNPVlVyHALLQnAxrwfgcFopCoJwS6WNY3FLCsaZmBsPCkAQmjrQs1IgDGGj6Jwkg7fdB2cLwCggK9d17etpBwLAMCILZzx0LE5CUGgUP0HEwBcFwAQ0LQlZ/RAURfVEoT1L8nA3fDbCCAA8gwtCE0DpBYDVRjiDTM7tI4IF/TTmCqO0o5rPtVWVF9yJRMQBMeFgX0EMQeAsETwNUAYwAKAAangmAUmTAK7Td/CCCIYjsFIMiCIoKjqDTujlAYRgoNY1j6HgUR/ZACyoIk1Tszhg4ZqYJ2WGY%2B1tEqfgQK4Yx%2BOUwShH0JQDOUuRpAIYc5CkCcMNM/RlBUVSdCMjSeM0eiB9UXQNOnMeZ5Moz5%2BMti52XsxcAsCjnaseiS5gaw8BtW2fTTh0cKoAAcUY4VGkh7MAyDIHsKO4puEDHVYlikHsuCECQ8bXSvHgI3qmyN7wgNaHMj3Pa9m0cB9pAyzGUa4tmCYxpIw/QmYt9j6Qu37f3v3/bd90LFBhDPiCICCwwgPDRI0NM6YHwEQTOOthCqgNtIRBJs1ASzOJ3XgFIRaJFlt3Dg21P5fX7mTUcoCrRUD2EPEeY8J5TxnlwOeewF6oF3sWfecxD4AIWEaJgWA4isjepfXgMtJAbFxBoTM0INiSBjFwB80IJEbCjCQvuP1bB/yPg9UgT0XoiI2L3b%2BmidEnxEWYYxvAf7/yBuYkCxAwJ%2BEkEAA)

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<char type>
class A
{
public:
  // ...
  void worker_method();
};

// function acceppts only upper case letters and redirects to lower case one
template<char type>
    requires (type >= 65 && type <= 90) // upper case letter
void A<type>::worker_method()
{
    std::cout << "redirecting " << type << " to lower case one\n";
    A<type + 32>{}.worker_method(); // calls lower version
}

// Instantiation for the 'c'-type.
template<>
void A<'c'>::worker_method()
{
    std::cout << "processing 'c'\n";
}

template<>
void A<'e'>::worker_method()
{
    std::cout << "processing 'e'\n";
}

template<>
void A<'E'>::worker_method()
{
    std::cout << "processing 'E'\n";
}

int main()
{
    A<'c'>{}.worker_method();
    A<'C'>{}.worker_method();
    A<'E'>{}.worker_method();
}
```

This way you can redirect instantiation with an upper case to lower case ones **iff** there is no specific upper case overload available.

program prints

```
processing 'c'
redirecting C to lower case one
processing 'c'
processing 'E'
```

Comment: `requires (type >= 65 && type <= 90)` -> `'A'`, `'Z'`.